# php read file and create drop down menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have following php code which create Drop-Down menu reading text file which contain name

files.txt

```
JAMES
MARK
TONY
```

drop-down.php

```
<?php
$path = "files.txt";
$file = fopen($path, 'r');
$data = fread($file, filesize($path));
fclose($file);

$lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,$data);
echo '<select name="file">';
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo '<option value="'. urlencode($line).'">'.$line.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Here is the POST section of code, it is a loop

```
foreach ($_POST["bname"] AS $id => $value)
{
...
...   
USERNAME: "'.$_POST["file"][$id].'"
```

Everything working but when i submit data to other form i am getting only first letter of users like if i select `JAMES` and submit data i am only getting `J` letter in `.$_POST`. I want Full name `JAMES`, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: can you show us the script where you use `$POST`?

Comment: What is probably happening is you are saying I only want the first character of the string `$_POST["file"][0]` or something similar somewhere, but we need to see the part where you echo it out.

Comment: Yeah this worked fine for me. It must be what ever you're posting.

Comment: @sgroves - I have edit my question and add `POST` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute of your select is wrong, must be:

```
echo '<select name="file[]">';
```

or

```
echo '<select name="file[someNumber]">';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Id, because that is saying "I want this value, and the second part says which character" (at least the way that you are using it). Try this:

```
"USERNAME " . $_POST["file"]
```

Strings are treated like arrays in PHP.

So if  you had the string `kitty`

```
$string = "Kitty";
echo $string[0]; // prints "K"
echo $string[4]; // prints "y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try read the txt file with `file()`, it adds the rows directy into an array, then use `for()` to traverse the array.

```
<?php
$path = "files.txt";
$lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$nrl = count($lines);
echo '<select name="file[]">';
for($i=0; $i<$nrl; $i++) {
  echo '<option value="'. urlencode($lines[$i]).'">'.$lines[$i].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```